# Recurrence relation for T(0) = 1, T(1) = 0, T(n ) = 2* T(n-2)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I am trying to find the recurrence relationship for the above expression.

I deduced that:

T(n) = C*T(n-2)

T(n-2) = 2C*T(n-4)

T(n-4) = 3C * T(n-6)

...

T(n) = k/2C * T(n-k)

I am stuck here. Is this the correct approach? What is simplified recurrence relationship without having T in simplified equation?

Comment: Doesn't look right - where's that `2*` going when you go down each step? (hint. this is probably exponential)

Comment: This looks like it has two cases: 2^(n/2) for even n, and 0 for odd. There is probably a way to write that in a single expression with a floor operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's observe the behaviour as we expand this function `m` times:

```
T(n) = 2^2 * T(n - 2*2)
     = 2^3 * T(n - 2*3)
     = 2^4 * T(n - 2*4)
     = ...
     = 2^m * T(n - 2m)
```

When `n` is:

- Even: `n - 2m` eventually equals zero, which means that the maximum value is `m = n / 2`, and that `T(n) = 2^(n/2)`
- Odd: " eventually equals 1, which means that `T(n) = 2^(...) * T(1) = 0`

If we wanted to write this in a single expression:

```
T(n) = (1 - n + floor[n/2]) * 2^(n/2)
```

Comment: This makes sense! So the reason why there are two results is because of the T(0) = 1 and T(1) = 0. So if were to prove this by induction will I have to prove both the even and odd case?

Comment: The iterative step will be the same for both - just prove that if true for T(n) then also true for T(n-2) etc, but the base case step will be different yes.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a python program and found the relationship:

```
def rec(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    elif num == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 2 * rec(num - 2)
```

And after several test, I found this rule:

> index  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 7, 8....
>
> result 2, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 16....

So the result might be 2^(n/2) when n = 2k && 0 when n = 2k + 1  (k belongs to Z)

Comment: I believe that is 2^(n/2), not 2^n. e.g. 4 = 2^(4/2)